# Haproxy "send-proxy" unknown protocol -- speaking not SSL to HTTPS port?

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy, httpd.conf

10.22.12.54 haproxy IP Address

10.22.12.55 Apache web IP address

fqdn  hasan.example.com resolved in 10.22.12.54

**In My haproxy config**

---

```
global
     log /dev/log   local0
     log /dev/log   local1 notice
     maxconn 100000
     chroot /var/lib/haproxy
     stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd 
     listeners
     stats timeout 30s
     user haproxy
     group haproxy
     daemon
     ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
     crt-base /etc/ssl/private
 defaults
     log    global
     mode   tcp
     maxconn 1000000
     option httplog
     timeout connect 5000
     timeout client  50000
     timeout server  50000
     errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
     errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
     errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
     errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
     errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
     errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
     errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http 

frontend Front-"443"
    bind *:443
    mode tcp
    use_backend hasan
backend hasan
    mode tcp
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server hasan 10.22.12.55:443 send-proxy-v2
```

---

**APACHE WEB CONFIG**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName         hasan.example.com:443
 DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/
 ErrorLog       logs/ssl_error_log
 TransferLog    logs/ssl_access_log
 LogLevel       debug
 SSLProxyEngine     on
 SSLEngine      on
 SSLProtocol    all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
 SSLCipherSuite     HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
 SSLCertificateFile     /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/cert.pem
 SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/key.pem
 LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
 LogFormat      "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
 CustomLog      "logs/ssl_access_hasan_log" combined
 ErrorLog       "logs/ssl_errors_hasan.log
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**RemoteIPModule Configuration**

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 10.22.12.54
```

---

**Note:**

My certificate CN same in apache ServerName directive

My certificate and private key located in

**haproxy:** /etc/ssl/certs/ and /etc/ssl/private/

**apache web:** /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl

---

**In apache Log I observed**

[Thu Aug 15 11:36:23.368657 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 4058] SSL Library Error: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol -- speaking not SSL to HTTPS port!?
[Thu Aug 15 11:36:23.368660 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 4058] [client 10.22.12.54:41800] AH01998: Connection closed to child 2 with abortive shutdown (server hasan.example.com:443)
[Thu Aug 15 11:36:24.704663 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 4056] [client 10.22.12.54:41804] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server hasan.example.com:443)
[Thu Aug 15 11:36:24.704820 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 4056] [client 10.22.12.54:41804] AH02008: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server hasan.example.com:443)
[Thu Aug 15 11:36:24.704840 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 4056] SSL Library Error: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol -- speaking not SSL to HTTPS port!?

---

**NOTE:**

Without send-proxy everything work properly.

But I need using

1) Using TCP mode in HAPROXY

2) send-proxy in HAPROXY BACKEND

3) RemoteIP module in Apache Web side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version from Base CentOS 7 repo (when i use yum install httpd) 
can not understand 
"RemoteIPProxyProtocol On"

Same situation in the latest apt repository.

I resolve this issue when I **compiled apache httpd from source code **.